# Is it possible to insert data into UUID?

Tags: cryptography, hash, md5, sha, encoding

Is it possible to insert arbitrary data into UUID? 
Let's suppose we have an MD5\SHA hash of something... can we encode that data into a valid UUID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No UUID have a specific structure which doesn't take into account appending any custom user-generated information.

Also consider how bad this idea is, UUID are a type of identification which should somehowe resolve to the actual data, identification is a mean of decoupling the desired entity from the actual content of it.
An identification should be unique and unchangeable, while the actual data may change over time.

If you start putting data into the identifier you're messing with the very goal of an identification, being unique and unchangeable.

**EDIT**:

*The version 3 or 5 UUID is meant for generating UUIDs from "names"
   that are drawn from, and unique within, some "name space".  The
   concept of name and name space should be broadly construed, and not
   limited to textual names.  For example, some name spaces are the
   domain name system, URLs, ISO Object IDs (OIDs), X.500 Distinguished
   Names (DNs), and reserved words in a programming language.  The
   mechanisms or conventions used for allocating names and ensuring
   their uniqueness within their name spaces are beyond the scope of
   this specification.*

Source: http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc4122 paragraph 4.3

Comment: ** Indeed, what I wanted to put inside was an hash of random data.. but a unique and specific data.

Comment: If it is random unique hash data why not trusting the UUID's own generation of random unique hash data? Otherwise why not using your random hash/data as key and leaving UUID alone? I think I'm not catching fully your intent.

Comment: Because the existing system accepts UUIDs but I want the data to be marked into the UUID.

Comment: Isn't UUID v3-5 a feasible solution?

Comment: In theory inside UUID v3 you should put a URL which is itself unique. Of course you can also put your MD5/SHA hash but I would consider deeply the objections I have made in my answer before taking this path.

Comment: It is not mandatory to use URLs as namespace can, by standard, indicate an URL, an OID, a DN, (and so $node content). 


On top of that, you can generate your own namespace and provide any kind of string inside $node.


If you're worried about the hash being unique, it will; or about being random maybe, it will. Because it's public RSA key (uniqueness, of course, is enforced by us).


I'm just looking for a "marked" UUID.
Theoretically it could even look like an UUID v3 (but with "chosen" random data - random data, is just chosen before by the PRNG, that's all: it still is random).

Comment: true.. I'm fixing my answer

Comment: it's actually standard practice to embed data into uuid's for things like document type, version, creation date, legacy id if moving over from a legacy monotonic id ... not weird or bad